# ls: ordering by timestamp (reversed) and if the timestamp is the same order by name (not reversed)

Tags: shell, ls, filenames, date, sort

I'd like to order a directory by reversed timestamp, but if the timestamp is the same order by name (not reversed)

Using `ls -tr` if two files have the same timestamp order by name but in reversed mode

Comment: To what accuracy do you want to measure timestamps for "sameness"? You've got somewhere between nanosecond and two-second intervals (partly depending on filesystem type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
stat --printf "%Y %n\0" * | sort -z -k1,1n -k2
# or quoted file names:
stat --printf "%Y %N\0" * | sort -z -k1,1n -k2
```

- First sort-criteria is field 1 (`%Y` -> timestamp (accuracy: seconds)), **n**umeric sorting.
- Not **r**eversed as `ls -t` sorts with "newest first", which is already reverse from `sort -n` but you could use `-k1,1nr` to change that.
- Second sort criteria is everything from field 2 to the end of the line (`%n` or `%N` --> filename)
- Use zero-delimiter to avoid problems with filenames including `\n`.

and then fix the format to your liking with `tr` and/or `sed`:

```bsh
... | tr '\0' '\n'
# or just print the filenames:
... | sed 's/^[0-9]* //;s/$/\n/;s/\x0[0-9]* /\n/g'
```

Output:

```bsh
$ touch d; sleep 1; touch b c; sleep 1; touch a;
$ ls -tr
d  c  b  a
$ stat --printf "%Y %n\0" * | sort -z -k1,1n -k2 | sed 's/^[0-9]* //;s/$/\n/;s/\x0[0-9]* /  /g'
d  b  c  a
```